# Como hacer un Parallax con Bootstrap, si en mi sitio web el menú es fijo?

Tags: bootstrap

Un gran saludo :)

A penas es la primera vez que hago un sitio web con Bootstrap, Mi sitio web tiene primero el logo central, fijo y luego el menú, casi muy tradicional. Sin embargo con las secciones siguientes 2 o tres secciones mínimo deseo anexarle el efecto Parallax, ya tengo la imagen de fondo.

No se que me sugieran ¿Como podría hacer en mi caso?

Gracias =D

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--HEADER-->

<header>
  <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html">
      <img class="center-block logo" src="imagenes/Logo.png">
      </a>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- MENU -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
    
  </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">INICIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="nosotros.html">NOSOTROS</a></li>
          <li><a href="servicios.html">SERVICIOS</a></li> 
          <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> 

<!--CONTENIDO INICIO-->

  <section>
      <video class="video" src="Videos/v_inicio1.mp4" autoplay loop/></video>
  </section>


<section class="container-fluid">
<div class="novedades">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="text-center"><b>NOVEDADES</b> EN SERVICIOS</h1><br><br>
    
    <p class="text-center">En <i>José Miguel, Arte y Belleza</i>, lo invitamos a conocer nuest...recios marcada por la calidad y el interés en lograr una satisfacción y una mejora constante, para así ser su gran aliado en belleza.</p><br><br>
   
    

    <video controls poster="imagenes/v-novedades.jpg" class="center-block" width="600"  src="Videos/v_inicio2.mp4"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>

    <br><br>

            <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">¿Con que productos trabajamos?</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">“José Miguel arte y belleza”, comercializa y trabaja con los productos desarrollados ...
        a las necesidades y expectativas de nuestros clientes.</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- FOOTER -->  
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-left">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">CONTACTO:</h6>
            <h6 class="text-muted">
            Carrera ... Local 2<br>
            Santa... la Ronda.<br>
            Teléfonos: ... 641818.<br>
            </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
            <div class="redes-footer">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 

        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <p class="text-muted small">José Miguel, arte y belleza @2016.<br> Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el body esta bien, pero haber prueba en el html que puede ser mas óptimo.

```
        html
        {
            background-image: url(img/fondo.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-position: center center;
              background-attachment: fixed;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;

        }
```

Comment: Hola gracias, sabes para hacer más clara mi pregunta, como te das cuenta en un parallax el menú es pegajoso, no sé como podria hacer que no afecte el header donde esta el logo y el menú, y que lo demás entonces tenga el efecto Parallax.